# Why Laravel database settings do not change upon during testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.8

I have a laravel project eith6 the following configuration:

```
return [
    'default'     => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'default'),
    'connections' => [
        'default' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'read'     => [
                'host' => env('DB_HOST_READ', '192.168.10.70'),
            ],
            'write'    => [
                'host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE', '192.168.10.70'),
            ],
            'port'     => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_NAME', 'default'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
            'sslmode'  => 'prefer',
            'timezone' => 'Europe/Athens',
        ],
    ]
];
```

And I want to specify the settings for a test database whilst I run phpunit. Therefore I hardcoded it in phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="default">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="false"/>

        <env name="DB_NAME" value="test" />

        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>

    </php>
</phpunit>
```

And I made the following test:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

class SampleTest extends BaseTestCase
{
   public function testSettings()
   {
      dump(config('database.connections.default'));
      dump(env('DB_NAME'));
   }
}
```

But the following result is returned:

```
array:4 [
  "default" => array:12 [
    "driver" => "pgsql"
    "read" => array:1 [
      "host" => "192.168.10.70"
    ]
    "write" => array:1 [
      "host" => "192.168.10.70"
    ]
    "port" => "5432"
    "database" => "default"
    "username" => ""
    "password" => ""
    "charset" => "utf8"
    "prefix" => ""
    "schema" => "public"
    "sslmode" => "prefer"
    "timezone" => "Europe/Athens"
  ]
]
"test"
```

So how come that settings are configured wrong whilst environment returns the expected value? And why the env does not evaluate the appropriate values in setup?

Is there a vay to force config values during testing regardless what .env says so?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is because of roque cached settings. It is advisable to clean any settings caches during `setUp`:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

class SampleTest extends BaseTestCase
{
   protected function setUp(): void
   {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('config:clear',['--env'=>'testing']);
        Artisan::call('config:cache',['--env'=>'testing']);
        //rest of test setup.
   }

  // Rest of tests here
}
```

Therefore, you will always have fresh settings.

Comment: No sir, never cache anything in a test... remove those 2 lines of codes, don't cache... it is a test, it has to be pristine all the time...

Comment: So how I can tell in laravel NOT to cache the test settings?

Comment: It does not cache by default, it does not cache anything. Maybe you have something in your code that it is caching config, but by default, it does not do that.